# OpenGL ES cross platform development

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to develop a small 3D game running on both Android and IOS mobile devices.

1- Should I implement EGL using within 3D logic or left it been implemented in Object-C or Java? which way should I go and why?

2- Should I use C or C++ for game logic? it is said C has better run time performance but harder to design due to it is not OOP C++ and vice versa. I have some experience with Java so I prefer OOP more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already considered to use a multiplatform library? For example:

[libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

Especially if you are targeting for both platforms, such a library might be helpful.

I can only speak for Android a bit:

1. It actually makes no real difference, the Android API just provides calls for the same OpenGL C-functions, but still more comfortable, better supported and the recommended approach. Anyway there is [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) which allows to load original C/C++ code given the case you want to port some code from another platform (or develop for several platforms).
2. In my opinion the performance is mostly limited by the graphics (number of objects, size of textures etc.), usually not much by game logic, so Java would be more convenient.